# Is there a way to quickly go through all the compilation errors in an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

My goal is to be able to use the keyboard to quickly go through all the compilation errors in a project. It is like using F2 or shift-F2 to go through errors in a single file, except not only the single file, but every file in the project.

I could even accept having to open all files with errors (or even all the files) and using shift-F2 and ctrl-F4.

The build output panel in Android Studio seems to only allow clicking via a right click menu to go to the next problem which is incredibly slow.

A problem file can be fixed, and then a build triggered with ctrl-F9 to seek to the next file, but that is also incredibly slow.

I have done some googling in an attempt to find a solution, but am only finding irrelevant results.

To me, it seems to be a simple to implement UI feature with a great quality of life improvement that should exist. Does it exist or does an issue need to be created?

Comment: How often do your projects have a ton of errors?  Normally you fix those as you go so there are either none, a small number due to code you've just written, or a ton but all due to one mistake you just made.  Having a ton of compilation errors to go through isn't normal.  If this is really a problem for you, you should probably change how you work.

Comment: The problem crops up every time I change parameters to a function.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with that is to find all usages of the function.  Right click and find usages.  It opens a find window with all the places its used.  That way you don't need to even compile, just do it as soon as you're about to change the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to use the keyboard to go through errors in the build panel.

CTRL-Tab-B will move focus to the build panel. Then Tab will move focus to the build output tab of the build panel. Then you can arrow over to the next problem file and hit enter to put focus in the source file at the error.

Quite a lot of key presses to go to the next error in a project.

Update: An even better way is to press alt-6!